# Selenium Command to scroll in Selenium Until Element is visible

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to click on the  Scroll button until the element is visible . Can any one help me to achieve this

Comment: Which element? Whats the id/name/css/xpath of the element?

Answer (score 0):

This will move to the element located by the xpath.

`Actions actions=new Actions(getDriver());
actions.moveToElement(getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//Your xpath here"))).build().perform();`

Comment: Did you try clicking using JavascriptExecutor?